# Protecting .NET framework 4.x web API with Identity server 4 in

Tags: identityserver4

I am working with identity server 4, and I know it is now on ASP.NET Core, and it is fine.

But I have a [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework#Apache_License_2.0_release) application that is on .NET 4.6.2. I wonder how is possible to protect these APIs. Or is it possible at all? Or I should change my web API to ASP.NET Core?

I searched everywhere, but all samples are with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I am having the same issue, great question ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Identity Server 4 doesn't care what the client is. You can test ID4 with a console application if you want, right?

You see, when it comes down to it all ID4 is basically is a REST Web API itself with some well known endpoints using the Open ID Connect/oAuth2 protocol on top of the HTTP protocol. Just look at the samples with console clients here to gain more understanding of how you'd like to set up your client: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Clients.

So, that your client happens to be a Web API net462 does not matter. All you have to do is send requests to the urls of a hosted ID4. Maybe look into Katana's Open ID Connect middleware to make things easier for you: https://leastprivilege.com/2014/06/12/using-discovery-and-katana-middleware-to-write-an-openid-connect-web-client/. That is by the way a link to the blog of 1 of the creators of Identity Server. I suggest you browse through his blog to find more usefull information.

**Update token validation**

For token validation you'd want the token endpoint: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/token.html. I suggest to read into JWT tokens, because you could for instance look at Katana JWT middleware: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/01/15/using-json-web-tokens-with-katana-and-webapi.aspx.

Comment: Hi Danny and thanks for your complete answer. as you said the client is not problem my clients are android and ios application my access token server is asp.net core identity server 4 and i have api with net426. i want to use AccessTokenValidation in my api application and that is my problem.

Comment: Some of the helper URL's are now 404

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Clients. does not work anymore